# An example of Lebesgue measurable set but not Borel measurable besides the "subset of Cantor set" example.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question is to give and example of Lebesgue measurable set but not Borel measurable.

I know there exists subset of Cantor set that is not Borel measurable, since the cardinality of all Borel sets in $[0,1]$ is $\aleph_1$ while the cardinality of the subsets of Cantor set (defined on $[0,1]$) is $\aleph_2$, so it must contains subsets that are non-Borel measurable.

The problem is, the "cardinality of all Borel sets in $[0,1]$ is $\aleph_1$" requires something that is beyond the scope of first-year graduate level real analysis course. I cannot prove it using what I learned.

Can anyone give another example? Thank you!

Comment: The Continuum Hypothesis doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: The Cantor set is assumed to be defined on $[0,1]$, its subsets has cardinality $\aleph_2$, more than Borel measurable sets in $[0,1]$, which is $\aleph_1$, so there must be a subset of Cantor set that is not Borel measurable.

Comment: It is $\aleph_2$ if you assume the Continuum Hypothesis, but you do not need CH for [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) that $2^n>n$ even when $n$ is an infinite cardinal number.  So $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}>2^{\aleph_0}$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am not saying that because of Continuum Hypothesis so I cannot prove it. I am saying this example requires knowledge beyond the real analysis stuff, involving the structure of Borel sets, etc. So I am asking if there exists other examples within the scope of general real analysis level.

Comment: I understand what you were asking, but you were stating stuff about $\aleph$s that depend on the (generalized) CH without relevance to the argument.  Sorry I was unclear.